# List<string> object IndexOf returning -1. How?

Tags: c#, list, indexof

This is very baffling to me. Somehow the `IndexOf(string)` method of my `List<string>` object is returning -1 even though the value is CLEARLY in the List.

```
protected readonly List<string> validPrefixes = new List<string>() { "01", "02", "03", "FE", "E1", "E2", "E3" };
```

`string prefix` is "01"

[image]

`validPrefixes` index 0 is "01".

[image]

`indexOf` is -1. Umm... How?

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you `validPrefixes.IndexOf("01")`?

Comment: Please show the content of the `addr` variable.

Comment: Not dealing with something like a zero versus a letter 'O' are we?

Comment: What happens if u do `addr.Substring(0, 2).Trim();`?

Comment: @Amit `validPrefixes.IndexOf("01")` returns 0 as expected.
@BrendanGreen `addr` is "0138842e"
@DavidW No, it's definitely a 0 and not an O

Comment: So it's probably safe to say that `prefix!="01"`... Now, please compare their lengths...

Comment: Okay...how about posting the declaration of addr? Almost wonder if it's some encoding thing.

Comment: @Amit Hmm... yeah I bet there is a `\r` in there. Weird, but let me check.
Edit: Nope `prefix` length is 2 as expected.

Comment: Since the strings are similar, and the comment section deemed the option of an ascii clone to doom, there has to be an escaped character in the strings.

Comment: In fact, maybe add an assert about prefix=="01"....

Comment: Could the two string be considered as two different objects (references are different) ? What about to use the linq method : FirstOrDefault(p => p.Equals(prefix)) and test if it is not null?

Comment: @Prix `addr.Substring(0, 2).Trim()` did not help. I got the same string.

Comment: How is "addr" being delivered to the app? Not coming over a comm line like a serial interface, is it? Still wonder about encoding.

Comment: not that this addresses the problem, but just a friendly code review comment -- you don't need to perform the `.IndexOf()` again in the `else if`...just do `else if (indexOf == -1)`

Comment: @DavidW It is going over a serial interface sort of. I'm connecting to a Bluetooth Low Energy device which does BLE to serial. I wouldn't think that would effect anything.

Comment: @ethorn10 Yes, I realize this. I inserted that code so I could view the value of the `IndexOf` method at a break point.

Comment: It probably doesn't make any difference but just for grins I would do a getBytes on addr and compare them to the bytes of "01"

Comment: I'm wondering if there's an ASCII vs UTF8 encoding conflict snooping around

Comment: @DavidW It looks like you're right. `("01").ToCharArray()` returns `['0','1']` but `prefix.ToCharArray()` returns `['f','e']`. That's just awful.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Where did `'f'` & `'e'` come from? And is this a coincidence that you're also comparing with `'FE'`? If you'd do `prefix = prefix.ToUpper();`, will it find a match in the `IndexOf` call?

Comment: @Amit I'm not sure. Now that I think about it, "fe" should be the prefix of my previous addr string. Maybe my debugger is lying to me and the value of `prefix` is actually from the previous loop iteration. Also, I believe the values in `validPrefixes` should be lower case since I am calling `ToLower()` on the value of addr earlier in my code.

Comment: Yikes! That's even more of a departure than I might have suspected! Are you getting raw bytes from the device and converting to a string, or is that being done for you?

Comment: @JaredPrice - If your debugger is lying to you, first thing to do is technicians cure -> restart the computer (No need to unplug :-)

Comment: Another thing to look for is multithreading issues. Is it possible one of the relevant variables is changing during processing of these lines? (For example, `addr`..) That might cause you to think values _were_ equal to current value, but in fact weren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not sure why, but it looks like my debugger was lying to me. I believe what was happening was the values in `validPrefixes` needed to all be lower case since I was using the `ToLower()` method previously in my code which effected the `string addr` variable.

For some reason my debugger seemed to somehow be mixing iterations of a loop. I was only able to tell this was happening by assigning variables to a `char[]` using the `string.ToCharArray()` method.

`("01").ToCharArray()` was returning `['0','1']`.
`prefix.ToCharArra()` was returning `['f','e']`.

Somehow, the debugger was telling me the value of `prefix` was `"01"` while the value of `prefix.ToCharArray()` was `['f','e']`. The latter being what the value should have been from a different loop iteration.

Since I was checking for `"FE"` instead of `"fe"`, my code wasn't working, but my debugger wasn't exactly telling me this.

I am developing for iOS using Xamarin on my Windows PC using the Xamarin iOS Build Host. I have had weird things happen to me in the past by developing like this especially when it comes to debugging and breakpoints. So I'm going to blame the Xamarin Build Host.

Thanks to @Amit and @DavidW for helping me come to this conclusion.

Comment: did you debug release or debug assemblies?

Comment: Next time do `validPrefixes.IndexOf(prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`, that will make IndexOf not case sensitive too and it does not force you to generate a extra string with `ToUpper` or `ToLower`.

Comment: @Kai I debugged using debug assemblies.